# Communication between 2 web apps running in a azure web role instance

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have 2 web applications running in a web role and I only run single instance in the azure cloud. I would like to send and receive notifications between these 2 applications and any outsider should not have access to them.

1. That means, web service in both of them are out unless there is a
   way to block outsiders from accessing a web service and only a
   request from same system would succeed (May be vip and request ip
   comparison would do, anything beyond that?).
2. File system watchers. Create a LocalStorage and use it in both
   web apps and watch for files webappA and webappB in each other.
3. Use Azure Storage Queues.
4. MSMQ - not interested as its not supported in azure.

Could you please list other options available for me in azure web role
? Thanks in advance.

Note: Please avoid suggesting Internal Endpoint as I am running only a single instance with 2 web applications running in it.

Comment: A file systemm watcher on LocalStorage won't work. Local storage is local. :-) (Each VM has its own, as it's just the local disk.)

Comment: Judging from your requirements, I suspect an Azure Queue is just the thing you need.

Comment: Using Azure Queues is the option I'd vote for.  I've used them to facilitate communication between two roles in a few apps I've written -- I see no reason it would be any different for two apps within a role.  I haven't had any issues with it to this point (knocking on wood).

Comment: @smarx - I think he said both apps are on the same instance (a single one).  In that case the local resource would be available to both.  Not saying that is the best way to communicate however...

Comment: @dunnry Oh, I think you're right.

Comment: So based on all your comments and 1 answer, it appears that there is not any other way that I am not aware of. However, I would still be glad to hear any other way of internal communication between 2 web apps running in a web role instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up "private" web services to listen on Internal endpoints. These are not accessible via the outside world. You could have a WebAppOne endpoint and WebAppTwo endpoint, both marked Internal. You then just query the role environment to discover the assigned port for each, and fire up your ServiceHost.

Or... you could use a queue to pass information, as long as:

- You're ok with it being asynchronous
- You're ok with messages being looked at "at least" once
- You're ok with messages possibly being looked at out of order

Or... your apps could write information to an Azure table. No need to expose the table to the outside world.

Comment: I like all the storage suggestions (queues, blobs, tables, a combination). I'm not so sure about the "private" web service. My understanding is that these are two separate apps (not two roles within the same app), so an internal endpoint won't work.

Comment: +1 - Azure table is good suggestion - sort of a quick-and-dirty queue, right?

Comment: If you need a queue - use a queue.  It comes down to if you want async versus sync communication.   Use any of the storage solutions if you want async or just setup a localhost WCF service (2 of them) for sync communication (i.e. each web app has a listener and other is client).

Comment: It was pointed out by @dunnry that I misunderstood the question. There's a single WA app, a single web role, a single instance of it, and multiple things running inside that web role. So yeah, any sort of IPC communication could work too.

Comment: @David, how do you setup a "private" web service? I am not aware of any configuration that can restrict a web service to be private.

Comment: @user859375 - When you create your endpoint, make it of type Internal. This type of endpoint is only visible to roles within the same deployment. Your actual service code doesn't change at all. To your code, an internal endpoint is nothing more than a port number it listens on.